# How to dynamically parse a JSON object with shell jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, jq

I got a question about shell's jq. So my JSON object is:

```
{"1543446000": {"name": "John", "company": "foo"}, "1543359600": {"name": "Kate", "company": "bar"}}
```

The numers `1543446000` and `1543359600` are UNIX timestamps. How can I parse one of the JSON objects by the timestamp with a shell variable?

My shell script so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
URL="https://pastebin.com/raw/w7awz7kZ"
export DATE=$(date -d "$today 0" +%s)
JSON=$(curl -H "Accept: application/json" $API_URL)
JSON=$(echo $JSON | jq --arg date $DATE '.$date')
echo $JSON
```

Doesn't seem to work. My intention is to select the inner JSON object described by one of the timestamps, which are basically midnight of today. So I want to select today's data set.

Any suggestions?

Greets,
Innoberger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the full syntax for key access, as the dollar sign preclude you using the shorter form. The error message should provide this suggestion.

```
$ jq --arg date 1543359600 '.$date' tmp.json
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.$date
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.$date
jq: 2 compile errors
```

Note the error message

> 'try .["field"] instead of .field'.

You won't need the quotes, though, as that would be how you specify a literal key `$date`.

```
$ jq --arg date 1543359600 '.[$date]' tmp.json
{
  "name": "Kate",
  "company": "bar"
}
```